# Facing to real world feedback designs (here, Constant Current Generator)

Tags: frequency, current-source, feedback, constant-current, loop-gain

I still work on a current generator made with 2 opamps and a nMOS. If I find the bias point to understand how much my LED can be driven, I still have problems to find an affordable way to derive the transfer function, in order to understand the limits of the PWM signal on the non-inverting pin of the OA1.

Here the implementation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCFloW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know how to derive the transfer function of a simple OA based amplifier. But here there is one more OA in the loop (the OA2) and also a source degenerated MOS configuration amplifier.

Now, the problems are that I don't understand well how to derive the feedback loop gain of the OA1. Should it superimpose to the one related to OA2 to find the worst case of freq behavior? But then I need to insert the Ciss, Coss (and Crss too?) of the MOS.

This is the small signal circuit of the BUZ70:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYwrGM.png)</sup>

Where can I insert those capacitance and how can I use them to see how they affect the transfer function of the overall system?

I know that this mybe requires a too wide answer, and in this case you can ask to specify better a single part of my doubt. Thanks.

**EDIT0** (@Russell McMahon): the LED should be driven in DC and in PWM mode in order to dim the light digitally with a simple microcontroller. The PWM is applied on the 3.3V pin "+" of the OA1. When 3.3V the LED is at its maximum designed current (or in over current, too) and when the PWM is at 0V the LED will be completely shutoff.

**EDIT1**: I'm not search any "ready" solution. I'd like also to have the hints to continue a correct analisys by myself.

Comment: If the LED is only on or off and not modulated at 10's of Hz or higher then slow on/off can be applied as shown. If you just want dimming then just RC filtering higher frequency PWM (say 1 kHz up) and applying the DC to OA1+ will do what you want. If you want a comprehensive theoretical analysis I'll leve it to the people who enjoy such things. (Theory get applied when needs-must, but when needs-mustn't I usually prefer to do other things :-). | For small amount or more relevant practice-theory: Your 100:1 divider delivers 33mV at the sense resistor for V_PWM_max. That's applied to ...

Comment: ... an LM324 input with an input offset voltage of +/- 7mV max at 25C or 9 mV max 0-70C. Typical offset is +/- 3 mV or about 10%. 7 mV is about 20% of your maximum brightness setting so at the divider ratio shown the opamp swamps fine differences from other sources. An LM324 or LM358 is my opamp of choice in this application (as they are usually "good enough"  and cost around 5 cents in modest manufacturing volume in China (or India)) but I'd usually not go below about 100 mV Vsense full scale with typical offset errors of under +/- 5%  Vfullscale under typical temperature ranges. ....

Comment: .... If you want better than this you need some mix of higher Vsensemax or trimming or a better opamp (of which there are many, but probably none more cost effective overall). You MIGHT be able to get better results with an LM324 by making an instrumentation amp IF Voffsets tend to be matched within one package - which I've never investigated. Trimming is easy and somewhat effective but in most cases use of a superior op-amp would be preferred. | As you get under about 5% resistor tolerances start to matter if using eg 1% parts. [1% worst case errors in R2, R3 give about +/- 2% errors]

Answer (score 3):

It is not usual to use OA2. Instead use R2/R3 to divide down the 3V3 reference signal, and apply Rsense signal to OA1 inverting input directly. IF there is no PWM component or modulation component in this loop then it will usually be DC stable without any thought or effort.

You mention PWM in the text but do not show it on the diagram.
Where do you intend to apply PWM?
Do you want PWM frequency to appear at / modulate the LED? and/or are you applying a fast varying signal such as audio to modulate the PWM mark space ratio?
If not then there is "too much thinking" happening :-)
(unless PWM modulation is required on the LED or raw PWM is required on LED and the PWM "frame rate" is very high and the PWM mark / space varies rapidly.)

See diagram below - usually good enough.
PWM could be applied as eg smoothed DC to 3V3 point IF modulation not required.

[image]

---

**ADDED:**

**Slow PWM < 10 Hz:** If the LED is only on or off and not modulated at 10's of Hz or higher then slow on/off can be applied as shown in your diagram.My circuit with one less opamp section has no practical disadvantage that I'm aware of. [If it has any known practical disadvantages that I'm not aware of or have overlooked I'd be genuinely happy to hear of them].  Faster PWM will be affected by R2 R3 time constant effects but with R3 = 470 R and the stray but OA input capacitances concerned, OpAmp slew rate and bandwidth is also likely to matter with an LM324.

**Dimming only:** If you just want dimming then just RC filtering higher frequency PWM (say 1 kHz up) and applying the DC to OA1+ will do what you want. If you want a comprehensive theoretical analysis I'll leave it to the people who enjoy such things. (Theory get applied when needs-must, but when needs-mustn't I usually prefer to do other things :-).

More relevant theory which 'leaks over' into practice in this case:

Your 100:1 divider delivers ~= 33mV at the sense resistor for V_PWM_max.
3.3V x 470/47470 = 32.67 mV ~= 33 mV

That's applied to an LM324 input with an input offset voltage of +/- 7mV max at 25C or 9 mV max 0-70C. Typical offset is +/- 3 mV or about 10%.  Wee [LM324 datashneet page 4](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm224.pdf).
7 mV is about 20% of your maximum brightness setting so at the divider ratio shown the opamp swamps fine differences from other sources.
An LM324 or LM358 is my opamp of choice in this application (as they are usually "good enough" and cost around 5 cents in modest manufacturing volume in China (or India)) but I'd usually not go below about 100 mV Vsense full scale with typical offset errors of under +/- 5% Vfullscale under typical temperature ranges.
If you want better than this you need some mix of higher Vsensemax or offset voltage trimming or a better opamp (of which there are many, but probably none more cost effective overall). You MIGHT be able to get better results with an untrimmed LM324 by making an instrumentation amp IF Voffsets tend to be matched within one package - which is possible, but I've never investigated. Trimming is easy and somewhat effective but in most cases use of a superior op-amp would be preferred.

As you try to get much better than 5% accurate LED current then resistor tolerances start to matter if using eg 1% parts.
[1% worst case errors in R2, R3 give about +/- 2% errors. Rsense at 1% adds about another 1% overall. OA offset currents do not matter at these impedance levels.]

Comment: haha! I've should think about that. The voltage divider trick allow me to use a sense resistor even 100 times lower without 2 opamps. In my implementation, the OA2 will let me use a lower sense resistor, but in a more uselessly difficult way. :)


About the PWM, I've edited my question. The PWM is necessary to have the LED -digitally- driven by an MCU. No RF carriers or whatever. Just a duty cycle to make a stupid dimmable LED (1 = LED on, 0 = LED off). The frequency response that I want to derive, is either for pure "academic passion" and to figure out how much fast can be the PWM frequency.

Comment: But I will need to see if using an opamp less will improve or not the frequency response. But I think that will be improved, and for the "academic passion" thing, would be interesting to see how much.

Comment: The error of parts and offset is perfectly clear, thank you.
A question about the needs must and mustn't.
When such analisys is required? I see that here is not so useful maybe, but if I want someone to use this circuit, how can I tell to him/her what is a reasonable maximum frequency to be applied? So, about the PWM without RC, you've talked about the dimensions of the resistors on the OA1+ and do not considered the MOS. May I ask, respectively, how and why?

Comment: @thexeno re "Needs must ..." -> As noted "If you want a comprehensive theoretical analysis I'll leave it to the people who enjoy such things". I can do (almost) anything. Some things are harder or take longer or MUCH harder or take much longer. Some are a matter of cudgelling little used memory cells into re-action. Others are a matter of checking text books or internet sourced info or ... . Some are fun - and I often spend me happy and essentially wasted hours (as people can tell) wandering off on some new or old journey. Others are less fun, less used, ... .  The years flee, the universe ...

Comment: .... is infinite for practical purposes. That which I must not do or am not inclined to do is best left undone. Others will do it in my stead more willingly and/or more capably. | In this case the frequency response of the LED control loop may be relevant for stability reasons steady state, or for dynamic on/off response or if the PWM signal is being used to directly modulate the LED at full PWM frequency (eg carrier may be being sent to a tx elsewhere) OR if the PWM modulation is required to be seen (eg a voice transmitter). Each of these has a different requirement. In almost every ....

Comment: .... instance that I have encountered all that is needed is that a dimming envelope is turned into LED current "fast enough" to optically track a command signal - something like 10 Hz bandwidth would be adequate AND I know from much playing that making circuits like this work in situations like that is essentially trivial. If a paying client or a game worth playing (life is a very serious game) arrives I would look or re-look further. Until then ... "... I'll leave it to the people who enjoy such things." This is where I came in :-)

Comment: :) ok ok, I got it. Very helpful, anyway!